# displaying Events with date and time in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the full calendar to display assigned shifts with start and end time in full calendar. I will be getting data's in array and i am mapping the values into events.There, if i do it only for date it works properly. If i include time with it, it does not display the events.Could anyone help me out with this.Thanks in advance

```
let apiData = [["11/07/2018","10:00",,"16:00","morningShift"],["11/08/2018","10:00",,"16:00","Shift1"]] // dynamic
         var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var form = '';
        var today = new Date($.now());
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            slotDuration: '00:15:00', /* If we want to split day time each 15minutes */
        minTime: '00:00:00', /* calendar start Timing */
        maxTime: '24:00:00',  /* calendar end Timing */
        defaultView: 'month',  
        handleWindowResize: true,   
        height: $(window).height() - 200,   
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        events : apiData.map(([startDate,start,end,title])=>({
            start: new Date(startDate)+'T'+start,    //mapping date 
                                                     //  with time
            end: new Date(startDate)+'T'+end,
            title,
            className: 'bg-primary'})
          ),
          timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'

        });
    }
```

Comment: `new Date(startDate)+'T'+start` that is not how you declare a date in JavaScript and then add a time to it. You're mixing an object with a string. Run that in your console and see for yourself what junk it outputs. P.S. fullCalendar makes date handling easy for you by supporting strings directly or by letting you use momentJS objects, which are much easier to work with than native JS dates.

Comment: For example you might get something like `Fri Nov 09 2018 09:27:32 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)T16:00` . Total nonsense. I'm not sure how you expected this to work?? And it's easy to test.

Comment: try `start: moment(startDate+" "+start, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm")` instead. And then read [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/moment) and [this](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I concatenated start date and time from back end and passed it to js.Now  that works fine